# How to eliminate Boilerplate caused by too many onChange methods in react component

Tags: reactjs

I've been writing React component which is responsible for managing Book Add Form as well as Book Edit Form. At some point, it ended up with 300+ lines of codes. What bothers me the most is this code:

Book Title Is Changed In Form:

```
  onChangeBookTitle(event) {
      this.props.onChangeBookTitle(event.target.value);
      if (event.target.value.length > 0) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          errorMsg: {
            ...prevState.errorMsg,
            title: ""
          }
        }));
      } else {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          errorMsg: {
            ...prevState.errorMsg,
            title: "Title Cannot Be Empty"
          }
        }));
      }
    }
```

Book Author Is Changed In Form :

```
    onChangeBookAuthor(event) {
      this.props.onChangeBookAuthor(event.target.value);
      if (event.target.value.length > 0) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          errorMsg: {
            ...prevState.errorMsg,
            author: ""
          }
        }));
      } else {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          errorMsg: {
            ...prevState.errorMsg,
            author: "Author Cannot Be Empty"
          }
        }));
      }
    }
```

Book Date Is Changed In Form:

```
    onChangeBookDatePicker(date) {
      this.props.onChangeBookDatePicker(date);
      if (date.length > 0 && moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD", true).isValid()) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          errorMsg: {
            ...prevState.errorMsg,
            date: ""
          }
        }));
      } else {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          errorMsg: {
            ...prevState.errorMsg,
            date: "Please Pick a Publish Date"
          }
        }));
      }
    }
```

I wonder if there is a better way to organise / eliminate the code.
ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely refactor the repeating parts of the code away. For example, let's take the first two event handlers, and see how we can refactor them:

```js
     onChange(propHandler, field, errorMsg, event){
      this.props[propHandler](event.target.value);
      if (event.target.value.length > 0) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          errorMsg: {
            ...prevState.errorMsg,
            [field]: ""
          }
        }));
      } else {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          errorMsg: {
            ...prevState.errorMsg,
            [field]: errorMsg
          }
        }));
      }
    }
    
    onChangeBookTitle(event) {
      return onChange('onChangeBookTitle', 'title', 'Title Cannot Be Empty', event);
    }
    
    onChangeBookAuthor(event) {
      return onChange('onChangeBookAuthor', 'author', 'Author Cannot Be Empty', event);
    }
```

As you can see, most of the code can become generic and only the specifics are separated to each handler.

If there are other changes (such as the predicate in the third handler), those can be incorporated generically in much the same way.

Also, this refactor is not finished, since the `setState` function argument is also almost the same, so that can be refactored as well:

```js
     onChange(propHandler, field, errorMsg, event){
      this.props[propHandler](event.target.value);
      const fieldErrMessage = event.target.value.length > 0 ? "" : errorMsg;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        errorMsg: {
          ...prevState.errorMsg,
          [field]: fieldErrMessage
        }
      }));
    }
    
    onChangeBookTitle(event) {
      return onChange('onChangeBookTitle', 'title', 'Title Cannot Be Empty', event);
    }
    
    onChangeBookAuthor(event) {
      return onChange('onChangeBookAuthor', 'author', 'Author Cannot Be Empty', event);
    }
```

Comment: I would also make the generic function a utility function and import it the components where it's needed to reduce noise in your components.

Comment: very useful Kraylog ! I just did what you showed here. !! awesome. zero_cool, what do you mean? can you create a code snippet?